# Best way to write a conditionally selectable constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I have the following code in C++:

```
struct A;

struct B
{
    B(){}

    template<typename T>
    B(T param){}
};
```

I want the constructor template to be valid only when the typename `T` is convertible to the type `A`. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry,I mixed C# and C++, I am working in both languages and I got confused. I just edited the question in order to fix the code.

Comment: Be aware that MSVC2013 has issues with the best practice answers to this problem in my experience.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to *enable* the constructor *if* `T` *is convertible* to `A`? Use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible):

```
template <
  class T,
  class Sfinae = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, A>::value>::type
>
B(T param) {}
```

This works by applying [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error); if `T` is not convertible to `A`, the substitution will fail and the constructor will be removed from the set of candidate overloads.

Comment: The 2nd template argument doesn't really need a name. But it is good

Comment: @BЈовић I know, but I generally use precisely this name as a bit of inline documentation.

Comment: In conjunction with the note `14.8.1/7` of the standard, I find your answer very good. Thanks.